# Adding label to combobox PyQt5-6

Tags: python

I need to add an inscription inside the combobox that will not affect the items inside it in any way.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmJgY.png)

Perhaps there is an implementation in qt designer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't get any errors, I just need an example of how to add an inscription to a combobox